# Want to write a python module for VMware (ansible) to get the mapping from VM to Storage

Tags: python, ansible-2.x, pyvmomi, vmware-tools

How to exactly use the `pyvmomi` library to get the above `mapping`, I mean what data structures to use particularly. I suppose it should be done via data store.

```
def getdatastore(datastore):
try:
  summary = datastore.summary
  return summary.name
except Exception as error:
  print "Unable to access summary for datastore: ", datastore.name
  print error
  pass
```

tried with the above function but in vain

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to map "from VM to Storage"

Do you mean `vm.datastore` ?

If not, can you explain your self better ?
(I'm sorry I can't comment, dont have 50 rep)

Comment: Yes I meant vm.datastore

Comment: So you got your answer ?